# Why does my app stop responding when navigating to MainPage twice when connecting to serial port?

Tags: c#, uwp, serial-port

I am developing a simple UWP app which needs to listen to a serial port connected to an esp32 which has a rfid reader attached.

It needs to receive UID of card, navigate to new page, and then navigate back to the original page after a timer has elapsed, or a button has been clicked.

It is all working, except for the part where I navigate back to the original parent page. I believe it's because the app is trying to reconnect to the serial port, but it's unavailalbe. I've tested my theory by creating a setup button with the serial connection setup on this and it does work as expected.

So, does Page_Loaded fire every time the page is reloaded? Is there a function which only fires on the first loading of the form? I can't get disposing of the serial port to work at all, i just get an unhandled exception. I don't have a problem leaving the serial port open though, but this seems to be causing problems too!

Please see some sample code below:

```
private async void setupCOM()
        {
            string qFilter = SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector("COM4"); //please note this is hard coded to COM4 - probably need to modify this at some point.
            DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(qFilter);

            if (devices.Any())
            {
                string deviceId = devices.First().Id;

                await OpenPort(deviceId);
            }

            ReadCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            while (true)
            {
                await Listen();
            }
        }
```

I am trying to fire setupCOM function on Page_Loaded and it works on the first page load, but not when the page is navigated to a second time.

```
private async Task ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Task<UInt32> loadAsyncTask;

    uint ReadBufferLength = 64;  // only when this buffer would be full next code would be executed

    dataReaderObject.InputStreamOptions = InputStreamOptions.Partial;

    loadAsyncTask = dataReaderObject.LoadAsync(ReadBufferLength).AsTask(cancellationToken);   // Create a task object

    UInt32 bytesRead = await loadAsyncTask;    // Launch the task and wait until buffer would be full

    if (bytesRead > 0)
    {
        string strFromPort = dataReaderObject.ReadString(bytesRead);
        int fstLetter = strFromPort.IndexOf("Info");
        int lstLetter = strFromPort.IndexOf("Info", fstLetter + 1);
        if ((fstLetter >= 0) && (lstLetter > 0)) strFromPort = strFromPort.Substring(fstLetter, lstLetter - fstLetter);
        Debug.WriteLine(strFromPort);
        Debug.WriteLine("Read at " + DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern));
        //txtresult.Text = strFromPort;
        //serialPort.Dispose();
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(user_login), strFromPort);
        //navpage();
    }
    }
```

Above function to read and process the string received, then pass onto the new user_login form.

Next form has a countdown timer of 15 seconds, after which time the form will navigate back to mainpage. but it just stops responding to everything. I am pretty sure this is because it's trying to reconnect to the com port.

Does anyone have any ideas?

It's very frustrating, so if anyone could help I would be eternally grateful :)

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe You need to use [Page.NavigationCacheMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.navigationcachemode?view=winrt-20348) to cache the mainpage, so that you could navigate back to the MainPage that save the previous setting correctly. As follows:

```
<page NavigationCacheMode="Required" />
```

Comment: wow, that works!
actually I think I made the problem worse myself. I tried to disable the NavigationCacheMode in the hope it would destroy the page and open it again. I didn't fully understand the cache i think. but yes required works very well, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

> So, does Page_Loaded fire every time the page is reloaded?

Yes.

> Is there a function which only fires on the first loading of the form?

You could use a boolean flag to determine whether to execute your method:

```
private bool _hasBeenLoaded;
private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_hasBeenLoaded)
    {
        _hasBeenLoaded = true;

        //your code to be executed only once...
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you for your help. This approach works too! I didn't realise Page_Loaded fired each time the page was navigated back to. I was looking for a Page_Created function or something like that.

Comment: "Page_Created" is the contructor of the page.